# Hooking Up an RJ-12 Cable to a Raspberry Pi Pico W: Simplifying Data Collection

Tags: rpi.gpio, pi-pico, data-transfer, pi-pico-w

I'm looking to gather data from an industrial-sized battery with an RJ-12 port. My idea is to connect a Raspberry Pi Pico W to the battery using an RJ-12 cable for data collection. I'm considering using [this](https://www.tinytronics.nl/en/cables-and-connectors/cables-and-adapters/ethernet-and-telephone/rj12-to-6-pins-dupont-jumper-adapter) adapter. Is it even possible?

Comment: You accepted an "answer" but it is unclear what the actual question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cable used in RJ-12 connectors has a very small area and that could cause a large voltage drop.

The voltage drop is larges when the WiFi is used as it consumes most power.

So yes you can use it BUT with the low AVG/Area it could cause trouble.

Comment: What kind of trouble may i ask? I am planning to read the data along with running an http server. The data wouldn't be read all the time. Will it be too much for the pi?

Comment: A voltage drop could cause the Pico to reboot or crash/hang.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll buy the cable, test it out, and see if it manages to hold up.

Comment: You could stabilize the Pico with a large electrolyte capacitor close to the P.ico

Comment: How is this any different to the 8P8C connectors used for Ethernet which use similar cables?